# Why was he glad, his brother changed his last name?

Tags: movie, quotes, wizards-1977

In the 1977 film [Wizards](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076929/), Avatar says:

> Oh yeah... one more thing: I'm glad you changed your last name, you son of a bitch!

But neither Blackwolf, nor Avatar ever had a last name. What was he on about?

Comment: +1 for a question about Wizards. Just because we were never told their last name doesn't mean they don't have one.

Comment: *"They killed Franz! ..."*

Comment: @dmckee: I thought it was Fritz.

Comment: @Keith, I think you're right. It's been a while since I saw that movie...

Comment: @dmckee My friends still attest I *never* showed them the movie :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it was to imply that Avatar wanted to disassociate himself from Blackwolf as much as possible, probably out of shame of being related to him, especially after the horrible actions he'd taken against his own people.

Comment: Agreed he wanted to disassociate himself, but he could have said "You were never really my brother!" or something....

Comment: @Pureferret: He could have, but the way he stated it is a bit more subtle. (But that final phrase, if taken literally, is quite ironic.)

Comment: Right, but this to me seems much more cutting.  Almost as if Blackwolf no longer has any claim to his own past.  Avatar is effectively rejecting him not only as his brother, but as a part of his history.